# How to prevent pagenumber overlap footer in inserted document while using pdfpages

Tags: header-footer, pdfpages

I am using lyx 2.2.3 win7 64, miktex 2.9 and am trying to include multiple pdfs using `\includepdf` with pdfpages package.
Some of my pdf documents already have page numbers in the footer and the page number inserted by

```
\includepdfset{frame,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}
```

in my preamble, makes the page numbers overlap the text in the footer.
Is there some way I could have the pagenumbers in very bottom of left corner of the page.
I tried using

```
\includepdfset{frame,scale=0.8,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}
```

and it makes the included pdfs ugly although now the page number do not overlap.

Comment: Use `fancyhdr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\includepdfset{frame,pagecommand=\pagestyle{fancy}}
\includepdf[pages=-]{hi}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting two page numbers with the above code in the footer: center and on the right. I then changed in Lyx page margins: top and bottom to 2cm and headsep and footsep to 1cm; and put the following explicitly in preamble and now the numbers print fine with no pagenumber in center of the footer.

> \usepackage{fancyhdr}
>   \usepackage{pdfpages}
>   \pagestyle{fancy}
>   \lhead{}
>   \chead{}
>   \cfoot{}
>   \lfoot{}
>   \rfoot{Bates number\thepage}
>   \fancyfootoffset[R]{1cm}
>   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
>   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}